How do I measure the regularity of the distribution in a list of binary data?
Suppose I have a list list = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], which gives information about whether a person was sick on a day (1) or not (0), since the list has 15 elements, I consider the days 1-15. I now want to determine how "nicely" or regularly these sick days are distributed over the period.
A regular distribution would be, for example
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]

an unsightly one would be e.g:
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

I was thinking of either the Gini coefficient or the standard deviation of the distances. But I don't know how to deal with such a list for the second one, for example.
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]

Here, the value for the standard deviation of the distances would be 0, but the 1s are not well distributed.
What other possibilities are there?

Would it be fair to say that "regularly" means as close to a uniform distribution of locations of the 1's as possible?  If not, please elaborate on your intended meaning.

Here, the value for the standard deviation of the distances would be 0 Welcome to Cross Validated! How are you calculating the standard deviation to get zero?

@whuber I this case. Regulary refers to the degree of which the lengths of each run of 0's is be are equal length between each 1.

@Dave SInce i only have 1 distance value,  the SD is zero

What do you consider a distance value?

@Dave Element 11 to 12 has a day distance of 1

And day 1 to 2 has a distance of zero, so how are you getting zero standard deviation?

I think we need a bit more clarifications about what you are trying to do here. 1) You say 0/1 represents "sick/healthy days". If that were in fact true, the values would be highly correlated, and one would not expect "regular" positionning of the 0/1's (if I am sick on day $n$, I am much more likely to also be sick on day $n+1$); in fact one would expect clustered data. So something does not quite make sense here. 2)  The data looks like 15 Bernouilli trials, and your "regular" example seems to have $p=.5$. Is that what you mean by "regularly spaced"? Follows a Bernouilli with $p=.5$?

Uniformly Spaced $1$s
What @whuber suggests seems to match closest your examples of regular and irregular sequences:

[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] is about as close as it gets to uniformly spaced $1$s.
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1] is very non-uniformly spaced.
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0] is very non-uniformly spaced.

One way to assess uniformity would be by assessing each sequence's location of $1$s against a theoretical uniform distribution which ranges from 1 to the length of the sequence.
Testing against a known probability distribution can be done using the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test:
x1 <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
x2 <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)
x3 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)
y1 <- which(x1 == 1)
y2 <- which(x2 == 1)
y3 <- which(x3 == 1)

# Sequence 1:
ks.test(y1, "punif", 1, length(x1))
# 
#   Exact one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
# 
# data:  y1
# D = 0.14286, p-value = 0.9939
# alternative hypothesis: two-sided

# Sequence 2:
ks.test(y2, "punif", 1, length(x2))
# 
#   Exact one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
# 
# data:  y2
# D = 0.51923, p-value = 0.1579
# alternative hypothesis: two-sided

# Sequence 3:
ks.test(y3, "punif", 1, length(x3))
# 
#   Exact one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
# 
# data:  y3
# D = 0.76923, p-value = 0.1065
# alternative hypothesis: two-sided

To see whether the $0$s deviate from uniformity, just switch which(x == 1) to which(x == 0).
(Doing so will reveal that the $0$s do not deviate much from uniformity at all in any of the three sequences.)
If anyone has suggestions to improve to this approach, feel free to comment!

There is a typo on line 5: should be y2 <- which(x2 == 1). Which explains why you get the exact same p-value for both...

Nice find, thanks @jginestet!
